# need c++ create a class named date

Tags: c++, class, date, object

Design a class called Date. The class should store a date in three integers: month, day and year.

The program should have a constructor that initializes the values of these three integers.

The class should also have three member functions setMonth, setDate and setYear to set the value of the three integers.

The class should have an additional showDate method that displays the date in the following format: `05/01/2014`

Demonstrate the class by writing a complete program implementing it.

Use the following main method to test your class

The output should be:

```
12/25/2012

6/16/2012
```

Main method

```
int main()
{
     // Create a Date object and initialize it
     // using the overloaded constructor.
     Date today(12, 25, 2012);
    // Show the date
     today.showDate();

    // Store a new month, day, and year in the object.
     today.setMonth(6);
     today.setDay(16);
     today.setYear(2012);

     // Show the date
     today.showDate();
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a homework question to me...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about turning SO into a 'do my homework for free' service.

Answer (score 2):

this shouldn't be hard for you! here is the header! all you have to do it write the functions now!

```
class Date{ 

   public:  

        Date();
        void SetDay(int day);
        void SetMonth(int month);
        void SetYear(int year);
        int GetDay();
        int GetMonth();
        int GetYear();
    private:
    int m_day;
    int m_month;
    int m_year;

    };
```